# Reverse engineering of an image filter

Tags: image, image-processing, filter, reverse-engineering, reverse

I am a beginner in image processing and I was trying to reverse engineer an application . My problem is that I have an image [Before](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55262925/Before.jpg) that is converted to this image [After](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55262925/After.jpg). I discovered that the whole process is done by using this 256x256 png map [OVerlay Map](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55262925/overlay_map.png). Can someone understand how can I simulate the process or what algorithm has been used?

EDIT: I have discovered that after 256x256 map this image [overlay](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55262925/blackboard10241024x1024.bmp) is overlayed.
EDIT2: I forgot to say the app is Instagram

Comment: Is there any one that knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Pixel by Pixel Operation (Namely, works on each pixel independently of other pixels) and you have access to the filter you can always create a LUT to mimic it.

For instance, for 8 Bit RGB image you create an image with $ {2}^{24} $ pixels with every combination of RGB values.
Then you apply the filter on it and keep the result as your LUT.
Now given an image every pixel has the corresponding value on the LUT and from there you have the result.

Enjoy...

Comment: What do you mean? Is it online filter?

Comment: You can do down sampling or send multiple images to create the LUT.

Comment: As I said, I am a beginner in image processing, so could you please explain furthermore this?

Comment: Unless you link to the filter or something I won't be able to say.

Comment: @Drazick i dont think LUT will work here. as the result of a pixel color is dependent on the position of the pixel. not the color.

Comment: @Rishabh876, Unless we have an access to the filter itself we'll never know.